# Circuitikz - Have european voltages sources but american voltages indicators

Tags: circuitikz

I currently have the following:

[image: Circuit]

Now the problem is with the voltage indicator Vc. I don't want to it to be an arrow but a `+  Vc  -` kind of notation. This is easily done by using the option `american voltages` in circuitikz. But I don't want to have the voltage sources to be indicated with circle +/- symbol inside. Thus how can I achieve `+  Vc  -` kind of notation without using the american voltages option?

The code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[%
  europeanvoltages,
  europeancurrents,
  europeanresistors,
  americaninductors,
  smartlabels]{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=0.8cm}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
\tikzstyle{every path}=[line width=0.8pt,line cap=round,line join=round]

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[every info/.style={font=\footnotesize}]
  \ctikzset{current/distance=2}
  \draw (0,0)
      to[V,l=$V_s$] ++ (0,2.5)
      to[short] ++ (1.0,0) node[right] {\tiny 1}
      to[open,o-o,l=$q_1$] ++ (0.65,0)
      to[short] ++ (0.5,0)
      to[L,l_=$L$,i=$i_L$] ++ (1,0)
      to[short] ++ (0.5,0)
      to[R,l_=$R_L$] ++ (1,0)
      to[short] ++ (0.5,0)
      to[open,o-o,l=$q_2$] ++ (0.65,0) node[left] {\tiny 1}
      to[short] ++ (2.0,0)
      to[I,l=$I_\mathrm{load}$] ++ (0,-2.5)
      to[short,-*] ++ (-1.2,0) coordinate (B)
      to[short,-*] ++ (-0.9,0) coordinate (C)
      to[short,-*] ++ (-4.6,0) coordinate (D)
      to[short] ++ (-1.1,0)
    (B)
      to[C,l=$C$,v=\quad$V_C$,-*] ++ (0,2.5)
    (C)
      to[short,-o] ++ (0,2.1) node[right] {\tiny 0}
      to[short] ++ (-0.55,0.4)
    (D)
      to[short,-o] ++ (0,2.1) node[left] {\tiny 0}
      to[short] ++ (0.55,0.4)
  ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add

```
\ctikzset{v/.append style={/tikz/american voltages}}
```

to your preamble and you get

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, also clever approach. Only need to remove the `\quad` now :-)

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve the problem is to separate the circuit into two \draw-macros. You could possible also do it by redefining the voltage source to american-style globally. Here is my suggestion:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[%
  europeanvoltages,
  europeancurrents,
  europeanresistors,
  americaninductors,
  smartlabels]{circuitikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=0.8cm}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
\tikzstyle{every path}=[line width=0.8pt,line cap=round,line join=round]

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[every info/.style={font=\footnotesize}]
  \ctikzset{current/distance=2}
  \draw (0,0)
      to[V,l=$V_s$] ++ (0,2.5)
      to[short] ++ (1.0,0) node[right] {\tiny 1}
      to[open,o-o,l=$q_1$] ++ (0.65,0)
      to[short] ++ (0.5,0)
      to[L,l_=$L$,i=$i_L$] ++ (1,0)
      to[short] ++ (0.5,0)
      to[R,l_=$R_L$] ++ (1,0)
      to[short] ++ (0.5,0)
      to[open,o-o,l=$q_2$] ++ (0.65,0) node[left] {\tiny 1}
      to[short] ++ (2.0,0)
      to[I,l=$I_\mathrm{load}$] ++ (0,-2.5)
      to[short,-*] ++ (-1.2,0) coordinate (B)
      to[short,-*] ++ (-0.9,0) coordinate (C)
      to[short,-*] ++ (-4.6,0) coordinate (D)
      to[short] ++ (-1.1,0) (B);
   \draw[american] (B)       
      to[C,l=$C$,v=\quad$V_C$,-*] ++ (0,2.5)
    (C)
      to[short,-o] ++ (0,2.1) node[right] {\tiny 0}
      to[short] ++ (-0.55,0.4)
    (D)
      to[short,-o] ++ (0,2.1) node[left] {\tiny 0}
      to[short] ++ (0.55,0.4);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Clever approach! I marked the other answer as the correct one since his approach is more flexible to me, since I want the notation to be american for all `v`'s.